# Why can't I insert the same ID into the 'id' column of my MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a messaging system and I'm trying to set it up so it will have a "conversation view" and so users can reply to a message. To do this I have to have a primary ID for each conversation in the table and then a separate unique ID for each message.

My problem is that when I try replying to a message I get this error:

> Duplicate entry '98' for key 1

It looks like it isn't allowing me to use the same ID in a column, but I don't have a 'unique' thing set in the table AFAIK.

I also tried to drop the PRIMARY for the `id` column but got this error:

[image]

The message is:

> #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

I don't understand why it won't let me insert the same ID into the `id` column, because as you know I need an ID for each conversation.

The `mysql_query` that I'm using to insert the reply into the table is:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (id, message_id, to_user, message, subject, from_user, date, time, date_short) 
 VALUES ('$id', '$message_id', '$to', '$message', '$subject', '$user', '$date', '$time', '$date_short')";

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pls dump your table description and post

Comment: UNIQUE Yes, is your answer... Solution is, make conversation_id...

Comment: primary keys are always unique, and you're trying to insert a row with a primary key that already exists. Don't try to group conversations together by having them have the same primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary key can not be repeated, otherwise it isn't so useful as a key, is it?  The primary key must uniquely identify the record.

The reason you're getting the error is that the column is set to be auto-number.  You have not added that column to a separate key, which is a requirement for auto-number columns in MySQL.

Add it to a key/index with that column first, then remove the PK attribute.  Make sure you have some PK in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have auto_increment without a key

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have `AUTO_INCREMENT` setup on your `id` field.  If this is the case, then the values in the `id` column must be unique.

Either remove the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute on that column (by redefining the column without `AUTO_INCREMENT` via an `ALTER TABLE` command), or don't specify the `id` value in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just going to create another column `conversation_id` as webarto in the comments has suggested and use the current `id` column for the unique message ID.

Answer (score 1):

First, untick `AUTO_INCREMENT` option on your column and as the second step, try to drop the index again

Comment: Thanks, I'll just create another column `conversation_id` instead, as webarto has suggested in the comments. The current `id` will be the unique message ID.

Answer (score 0):

`PRIMARY KEY`s are also unique.  auto_increment columns must be primary keys.  You can't drop `PRIMARY KEY` from a column without making it not auto_increment.

However, I don't think you should change your table like this.  You should keep your IDs and either create a new table with the data you need to update, or use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: I can't use `UPDATE` because when you send a reply... what would it update?

Answer (score 0):

Columns with primary keys can't have duplicates, otherwise they lose their uniqueness. MySQL will prevent same values. Having to alter primary key vales is also bad news. You may want to re-approach what you're doing and possibly create more tables.

Comment: He wants to drop primary key, he's not trying to add one